# AmMaps - heatmap for images instead of areas

Tags: javascript, amcharts, ammap

AmMaps has cool and easy feature to create heatmap for areas:
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/us-heat-map/

Is it possible to use it also for points (images) - to calculate image color basing on value, colorSteps etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, heat map features are not applied to images. However, it's pretty easy to apply the same principle using a very basic plugin:

```
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(map) {

  // check if `colorSolid` is set for `imagesSettings`
  if (map.imagesSettings.colorSolid === undefined)
    return;

  // calculate minimum and maximum value
  var minValue,
      maxValue;
  if (map.minValue === undefined || map.maxValue === undefined) {
    for (var i = 0; i < map.dataProvider.images.length; i++) {
      var image = map.dataProvider.images[i];
      if (image.value !== undefined) {
        if (minValue === undefined || (image.value < minValue))
          minValue = image.value;
        if (maxValue === undefined || (image.value > maxValue))
          maxValue = image.value;
      }
    }
  }

  // use map overrides if set
  if (map.minValue !== undefined)
    minValue = map.minValue;

  if (map.maxValue !== undefined)
    maxValue = map.maxValue;

  // set colors for each area
  for (var i = 0; i < map.dataProvider.images.length; i++) {
    var image = map.dataProvider.images[i];
    if (image.color === undefined && image.value !== undefined) {
      // we set colors for those images that don't have color set explicitly
      var percent = (image.value - minValue) / (maxValue - minValue);
      image.color = AmCharts.getColorFade(
        map.imagesSettings.color, 
        map.imagesSettings.colorSolid, 
        percent);
    }
  }

}, ["map"]);
```

Add it somewhere before the map code. Also make sure both `color` and `colorSolid` is set in `imagesSettings`.

Here's a complete [working example](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/ad6ffaaf2f7e45d3a9234024350e9630).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!